# SpellCheck error doesn't work wtih TinyMce 5.0.14 on IE and Edge

Tags: c#, tinymce-plugins

We are trying to upgrade the TinyMce version to 5.0.14 using the configuration below, all works apart from spellingcheck plugin error on IE11 and Edge browser, Chrome is fine. As a result the spellingcheck icon doesn't appear on the toolbar.

JS error is in nanospell/plugin.js line 43:

var Menu = exports.tinymce.ui.Menu;

Error: SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'Menu' of undefined or null reference

tinyMCEFeatures["Full"] = {
        mode: "specific_textareas",
        editor_selector: "tinyMceFull",
        add_unload_trigger: false,
        plugins: [
            "advlist autolink autosave link image lists charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
            "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen insertdatetime media nonbreaking",
            "table directionality emoticons template textcolor paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern"
        ],

```
    toolbar1: "bold italic underline | subscript superscript charmap | cut copy paste | undo redo | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | searchreplace | nanospell",
    toolbar2: "formatselect fontselect fontsizeselect | bullist numlist | outdent indent blockquote | link unlink anchor image | preview | forecolor backcolor | table | hr removeformat | print fullscreen | nonbreaking pagebreak",
    external_plugins: { "nanospell": "plugins/nanospell/plugin.js" },
    nanospell_server: "asp.net",
    height: 250,
    menubar: false,
    toolbar_items_size: 'small',
    browser_spellcheck: false,
    gecko_spellcheck: false,
    statusbar: false,
    setup: function (ta) {
        $.fn.tinyMceKeyPress(ta, $isInLine);
    }
};
```